# PNP React Web Parts in SharePoint Online suddenly stop working

Tags: sharepoint-online

I compiled a PNP Web Part sample for SharePoint Online on GitHub and published it in my SharePoint as an app. I was able to insert it and it rans. After about half a year, the Web Part is no longer working. It shows an empty area. In edit mode of the page I only get the error message that something is no longer working.
I have already recompiled and renewed it. But without success.

Does anyone have any idea what that could be?

```
[SPLoaderError.loadComponentError]:
```

Failed to load component "3a328f0a-99c4-4b28-95ab-fe0847f657a4" (ModernScriptEditor). Original error: Failed to load URL 'https://localhost:4321/node_modules/@pnp/spfx-property-controls/lib/loc/en-us.js' for resource 'PropertyControlStrings' in component '3a328f0a-99c4-4b28-95ab-fe0847f657a4' (ModernScriptEditor). There was a network problem. Make sure that you are running 'gulp serve' and you have run 'gulp trust-dev-cert'.

INNERERROR:
Failed to load URL 'https://localhost:4321/node_modules/@pnp/spfx-property-controls/lib/loc/en-us.js' for resource 'PropertyControlStrings' in component '3a328f0a-99c4-4b28-95ab-fe0847f657a4' (ModernScriptEditor). There was a network problem. Make sure that you are running 'gulp serve' and you have run 'gulp trust-dev-cert'.
CALLSTACK:
Error
at t [as constructor] (https://modernb.akamai.odsp.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-pages-assembly_de-de_32ae41951859b0521f1bd14591503f06.js:66:19823)
at new t (https://modernb.akamai.odsp.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-pages-assembly_de-de_32ae41951859b0521f1bd14591503f06.js:67:9700)
at Function.e.buildErrorWithVerboseLog (https://modernb.akamai.odsp.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-pages-assembly_de-de_32ae41951859b0521f1bd14591503f06.js:67:47234)
at Function.e.buildLoadComponentError (https://modernb.akamai.odsp.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/sp-pages-assembly_de-de_32ae41951859b0521f1bd14591503f06.js:67:43279)
at https://modernb.akamai.odsp.cdn.office.net/files/sp-client/chunk.systemjs-component-loader_de-de_fd0fd4fcfe3c7cb5bba0.js:1:11895

Comment: Can you add a whole error message please?

Comment: I added the message in my post above

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, it mentioned "Make sure that you are running 'gulp serve' and you have run 'gulp trust-dev-cert'", please check if you have run the "glus trust-dev-cert" and "gulp serve", the two command will preview the web part in localhost, please check if the web part can be previewed correctly.

More information:

https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part